# Date picker modal scrolls down the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, material-design

I am using Material Design and using its date picker. When date picker pops out, the page scrolls down. How can I load the date picker modal without the page scrolling down?

```
<input id="client-edit-birth-date" type="text" class="datepicker validate">
   $('.datepicker').pickadate({
selectMonths: true, // Creates a dropdown to control month
selectYears: 15, // Creates a dropdown of 15 years to control year,
container: 'body'
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and resolved it by setting container to html.

```
...
container: 'html',
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('.date-picker').datepicker( {
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        dateFormat: 'MM yy',
        onClose: function(dateText, inst) { 
            $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(inst.selectedYear, inst.selectedMonth, 1));
        }
    });
});
</script>
<style>
.ui-datepicker-calendar {
    display: none;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <label for="startDate">Date :</label>
    <input name="startDate" id="startDate" class="date-picker" />
</body>
</html>
```

[demo http://jsfiddle.net/DBpJe/5106/](http://jsfiddle.net/DBpJe/5106/)

Answer (score 0):

I do it by utilizing `beforeShow` function of datepicker:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
  ...
  beforeShow: function(input, inst)
          {
              inst.dpDiv.css({position: 'absolute'});
          }
  ...
});
```

There you can set the position of datepicker's dialog. You have to experiment to find out what kind of css parameters would more suitable in you case/page layout.